# Replace string is not changing value

Tags: python, string, replace

I am trying to replace any i's in a string with capital I's. I have the following code:

```
str.replace('i ','I ')
```

However, it does not replace anything in the string. I am looking to include a space after the I to differentiate between any I's in words and out of words.

Thanks if you can provide help!

The exact code is:

```
new = old.replace('i ','I ')
new = old.replace('-i-','-I-')
```

Comment: `replace` doesn't mutate the string in place.  You have to assign the replaced string to the variable.

Comment: Oh sorry. My exact code is:

Comment: 1) Make sure to look at the value in `new`, not `old`? 2) What is the *actual* input and the *actual* output for each case? (Surely not every case doesn't change anything!)

Comment: My old string has several I's throughout which are lowercase. I am basically trying to make them uppercase.

Comment: The string is part of Green eggs and ham by Dr Seuss, I believe. 'i am sam\nsam I am\nThat Sam-i-am!'

Comment: @user3449872 Do you want to replace `i`'s that are part of word as well? For example what would be the expected output for: `'jet ski is cool'`?

Comment: In addition to the accepted answer, once you've replaced 'i' with 'I', there are no '-i-' anymore.

Comment: Ok. Thanks all for the information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new = old.replace('i ','I ')
new = old.replace('-i-','-I-')
```

You throw away the first `new` when you assign the result of the second operation over it.

Either do

```
new = old.replace('i ','I ')
new = new.replace('-i-','-I-')
```

or

```
new = old.replace('i ','I ').replace('-i-','-I-')
```

or use regex.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "i am what i am, indeed."
>>> re.sub(r'\bi\b', 'I', s)
'I am what I am, indeed.'
```

This only replaces bare `'i'`'s with `I`, but the `'i'`'s that are part of other words are left untouched.

For your example from [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697934/replace-string-is-not-changing-value/22698095#comment34584115_22697934), you may need something like this:

```
>>> s = 'i am sam\nsam I am\nThat Sam-i-am! indeed'
>>> re.sub(r'\b(-?)i(-?)\b', r'\1I\2', s)
'I am sam\nsam I am\nThat Sam-I-am! indeed'
```